# How do I make HELO publish an SPF record? SPF_HELO_NONE - SPF: HELO does not publish an SPF Record

Tags: email, dns, spf

**Why is this question closed? There are hundreds of SPF record questions on StackOverflow that are not closed, why this one?**

---

**My environment: hMailServer 5.6.8 on Windows Server 2022 Standard**

Let's say I have two domains (I don't really own these domains, they're just examples), `www.myblog.com` and `www.mailserver.com`. They are both hosted on the same machine and have the same IP address `1.2.3.4`.

The blog site `www.myblog.com` uses `www.mailserver.com` to send emails. The site `www.mailserver.com` only serves as a mail server; it is not accessible from a browser. I have set it up so that when `www.myblog.com` sends an email to someone, the recipient's email server receives `SENT: EHLO www.mailserver.com`, but sees `SENT: MAIL FROM:<noreply@myblog.com>` message, so the recipient sees that the email came from `myblog.com`.

Everything is working fine so far. Recently I decided to check the "spam rating" of my setup at https://www.mail-tester.com. I sent an email to the spam tester using the setup described above, and I saw a warning under the *SpamAssassin* section that says

> SPF_HELO_NONE        SPF: HELO does not publish an SPF Record

My question is, how do I get rid of this warning? Are the DNS records as they should be? See below for the DNS records for each domain.

[image]

The DNS records for each domain are as follows (note the PTR record for 1.2.3.4):

```
IP address 1.2.3.4
PTR www.mailserver.com

myblog.com
Name            Type    Value
@               A       1.2.3.4
*               A       1.2.3.4
@               MX      10 myblog.com.
@               TXT     v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 ~all
dkim._domainkey TXT     v=DKIM1; t=s; k=rsa; p=[super long public key string]

mailserver.com
Name            Type    Value
@               A       1.2.3.4
*               A       1.2.3.4
@               MX      10 mailserver.com.
@               TXT     v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 ~all
```

Comment: Fixing this will have no effect on your spam score (it is already greater than -0.5).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know it's a very insignificant warning, but I want to know what it means so I understand SPF and DNS better

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/1064046

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've seen that question before, but the question (and answer) doesn't clarify what to do in my particular setup. What specific DNS records and values do I add/change? I listed the DNS records in my question. What changes do I make?

Comment: Have you published SPF records for  your HELO/EHLO hostnames, as that post describes?

Comment: Also, did you try [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1064047/12923)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Apparently I haven't published SPF records for my HELO/EHLO hostnames, or else I wouldn't be getting the error. What do I do to publish them?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I cannot try that solution to the question because I'm not using postfix.

Comment: The two options presented in that duplicate are the only options open to you. Every mail server will have some config option to do that, so go read the docs for it. It's likely you don't need to change DNS at all, only the HELO name of your mail server to match your sending domain (which already has an SPF) – but the fact that it's happening at all suggests that the current HELO name is *not* the same as your MAIL FROM domain, so double-check how your mail server introduces itself to others.

Comment: @Synchro currently, I'm using hMailServer, and the EHLO message it is sending is "SENT: EHLO www.mailserver.com", and if I change it to anything else, I will get spam warnings saying that my EHLO domain doesn't match mailserver.com's PTR record

Comment: From the email tag: Use this tag for questions involving code to send or receive email messages. Posting to ask why the emails you send are marked as spam is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions about configuration of mail servers belong on Server Fault.

Comment: @Rob Can you move my question to ServerFault or do I need to re-write it?

Comment: I don't have that ability.

Comment: You're not getting some mix-up between `www.mailserver.com` and plain `mailserver.com`, since you don't list an SPF for the bare domain? It's common to have a hostname on the mail server and not on the MAIL FROM address, and that would be matched by a DMARC `aspf=r` policy, but you'd still need SPF records for both.

Comment: You can click on "edit", copy it from there, and paste over on ServerFault. Make sure you delete this one.

Comment: Its not a programming question and should be on ServerFault or WebMasters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the warning by adding an extra TXT record with the name "www" to the `www.mailserver.com` DNS:

```
mailserver.com
Name            Type    Value
@               A       1.2.3.4
*               A       1.2.3.4
@               MX      10 mailserver.com.
@               TXT     v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 ~all
www             TXT     v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 ~all <-- adding this record fixed the warning
```